# Fast Fourier Transform Open Code in c++

Tags: c++, image, fft

I have been looking up an open c++ code about FFT. I wanna process an image with FFT and I wrote a code but the code which is mine is not fast even so slow. 
I wrote it using four for loop that's way it is not efficient. The point is, is there is anyone can help me. I searched the internet fully, but i couldn't find any document or code file in c++. I do NOT wanna have a pre-written code by any lib. That's way please show me a site and I can write my code.
My code is here;

```
void NaiveDFT::Apply( Image & img )
{

     complex<double> dft[512][512];    

    for(unsigned u = 0; u < img.rows; ++u)
    {
        for(unsigned v = 0; v < img.cols; ++v)
        {
            std::complex<double> sum = 0;
            for(unsigned x = 0; x < img.rows; ++x)
            {
                for(unsigned y = 0; y < img.cols; ++y)
                {
                    std::complex<double> i = sqrt(std::complex<double>(-1));
                    std::complex<double> theta = 2 * M_PI * (((u * x) / img.GetWidth()) + ((v * y) / img.cols));
                    sum += std::complex<double>(img.at<uchar>(i, j)[0]) * cos(theta) + (-i * sin(theta));
                    //sum += std::complex<double>(std::complex<double>(imgData[x][y]._red) * pow(EULER, -i * theta));

                }
            }
            dftData[u][v] = (sum.imag() / (img.GetWidth() * img.GetHeight()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and you might get some help.

Comment: for fft in general try `fftw` and for fft on an image try `opencv`

Comment: Your links has been visited. I searched them already. I want a open code and i want to modify them. opencv functions are closed that's way i cant modify.

Comment: The method that you are using is going to be very slow because it is a direct method of calculating DFT. What you need is to change your code to use the Fast Fourier Transform method. You can take a look at the fft implementation suggested in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Implementation_with_C.2B.2B) for starters, but if you want a robust method that will be probably faster than your own implementation, use FFTW.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed, for a 2D FT, you need to FT in one direction first, then apply FT in the other direction. So, you are going to have two nested loops, instead of a four-layer loop.

Comment: Thanks your helps, i am trying now . ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KISSFFT is BSD-licensed:

http://kissfft.sourceforge.net

FFTW is GPL-licensed:

http://www.fftw.org